# Curl Post with a Loop (Field taken from a DB)

Tags: php, curl

I need your help.

Actually I'm doing a CURL post with X-Wsse auth and posting only 2 arguments, ID and Phone.
Everything is ok.

Now I need to pass a list of ID and phones. In which way I can do this? Post a file directly? Using a loop?

I have a csv file, but for simplify I upload this file on a DB, so I can take directly from there.

This is the actual code.

```
<?php

function make_nonce() {
$chars = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$random = "" . microtime();
$random .= mt_rand();
$mi = strlen($chars) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $random .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $mi)];
}
$nonce = md5($random);
return $nonce;
}

function make_token($username, $password) {
$nonce = make_nonce();
$ts = date ( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', time() + 290 );
$digest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce.$ts.$password, true));
return sprintf('UsernameToken Username="%s", 
PasswordDigest="%s",Nonce="%s",   Created="%s"',
               $username, $digest, $nonce, $ts);
}


$token =  make_token("username", "password"); // ### GENERO IL TOKEN


$headers = array( 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;    

charset=UTF-8','Accept-Charset : UTF-8', 'X-Wsse :' . $token);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "phoneNumber=38452136&idPratica=745");

curl_exec ($ch);



var_dump($ch);

 curl_close ($ch); 


  ?>
```

I have a list of 1000 phonenumber and relatives idpratica (ID).

What can I do?

I know the way for doing with just one record.

```
$fields = array(

    'phoneNumber' => '38452136',
    'idPratica' => '745'
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

and then use

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

Please help me